# Making on demand sub report hyperlink invisible

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a report with an embedded hyperlink to an on demand sub report. I am trying to make the hyperlink invisible and then place it on top of a text object so that when a user clicks on the text object, the link activates and takes the user to the sub report. i tried formatting the sub report font to crNocolor in the formula bar, but it did nt seem to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not enter the link details into the Hyperlink section of the text object in Format Editor?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do this.  I tried including the hyperlink as an existing report object but I an not able to include the sub report.

Comment: @user455580, PowerUser's answer below shows how to set up a Hyperlink on a text object. However, I notice you are talking about subreports - a subreport is not a hyperlink. Which do you have?

Comment: Yes,I have a subreport which cannot be included as hyperlink

Comment: OK, so rather than adding another text object, why not format the on-demand subreport so that it has the desired appearance of the text object? Right-click on the subreport object in the main report, select **Format Subreport...** and in the Subreport tab of the format editor set the subreport name to be the desired text, while setting the other options (eg. font and colour from the Font tab) in the other tabs as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your text object and **Right click->Format Text->Hyperlink** and you'll see the panel as shown below (picture is from the Standalone CR Developer XI).  I've never used this feature, but can you use it to link to your on-demand report?

[image: Example Pic]